# How do I display the results of basic shell commands in a Django 1.4 website?

Tags: python, django, shell

Currently have built static web pages with Django and was just wondering how would I go about displaying the results of a basic shell command, such as 'ls -l' on one of these web pages.

Would it be possible to specifically assign a certain div to display the results?

Comment: You are probably going to want to use templates: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/templates/

Comment: @PaulCollingwood currently using Templates for the web pages. I want an easy example of how to display results from a simple shell command. I seen in that web page, it showed you could create a method in models.py however I thought it would have been in views.py you would have done it like the response catavaran has done.

Comment: you can do it many ways. You could have a field on a model which when queried for it's value runs the command and returns the answer as the value for that model element. Or, as below, make a view do it directly. Either way you'll be passing data to a template.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `os` module to execute the command:

```
import os
from django.shortcuts import render

def command_view(request):
    output = os.popen('ls -l').read()
    return render(request, 'command.html', {'output': output})
```

And put the result of the command into the `<pre>` tag:

```
<pre>{{ output }}</pre>
```

Comment: To be safe and in case it's not obvious don't substitute `ls -l` with anything user supplied.

Comment: Out of interest why does it have to be inside a pre tag? I've followed your instructions and all I'm getting is a small white box the length of the div I put the pre tags inside with nothing being displayed in it. I'm testing this locally.

Comment: `<pre>` tag is used for preformatted texts. This means that text will be shown with monospaced font and linebreaks will be preserved.

Comment: If you get empty box then your command is not executed normally. What command do you run?  `ls -l`?

Comment: I've tried 'ls -l' and also 'pwd'. Decided just to set the output variable to 'This is the output' but that was also unsuccessful. Would it be possible to just output the results for example inside <p> tag? <p>{{ output }</p>

Comment: Of course you can output results in `<p>` or any other tag. Are you sure that you correctly spelled `output` in the `render()` call and in the template?

Comment: Just realised I had {'output:': output} in the views.py file, big thanks for your help!